# MySQLi Rows Not Loading

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, rows

i have a basic form that loads 15 dropdown boxes with the same topics in each box. this is a voting page where the user can vote for his favorite topic or his least favorite topic. the problem i have is that the topics arent being loaded when i tell them to. Here is my code.

PHP

```
<?php
$Vote = new Vote();

class Vote {

    public function GetTopic() {
        $Connect = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "Data");

        $Query = 'SELECT * FROM Topics';

        if($Gather = $Connect->query($Query))
        {
            while($Row = $Gather->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $Topic = $Row['Topic'];
                echo '<option>'.$Topic.'</option>';
            }

            $Gather->free();
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Error';
        }

        $Connect->close();
    }

    public function LoadTopic() {
        for($I = 15; $I > 0; $I--)
        {
            echo '<select><option>'.$I.'</option>'.$this->GetTopic().'</select>';
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Have you done any kind of debugging? Are your queries working? Is GetTopic even called? Does the database connection work?

Comment: Add this you your php code, on top, for debugging: `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);ini_set("display_errors", 1); `

Comment: yes my query is working i have echoed them out by calling the function on my page. all topics are being loaded. i am trying to load them into a option tag but its not working.

Comment: Biggest issue I see here is you aren't doing anything with `$vote` other than declaring it a `Vote` class.

Comment: @Jason i call the vote variable in my HTML to load everything. the Select tags are being loaded no problem because i am generating 15 of them on my page

Comment: @Sergio No error was returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use your function like this you should return your html-data instead of outputting it:

```
public function GetTopic() {
    $Connect = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "Data");

    $Query = 'SELECT * FROM Topics';

    if($Gather = $Connect->query($Query))
    {
        $html = "";
        while($Row = $Gather->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $Topic = $Row['Topic'];
            $html .= '<option>'.$Topic.'</option>';
        }
        $Gather->free();
        return $html;
    } else
    {
        //handle error
    }
    $Connect->close();
}
```

Comment: This works! i have one problem though, it is only returning one row when i have 15

Comment: I fixed it! i had to move the return $Html outside my while loop

Comment: Trying new database connection per `select`?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try something a bit more appropriate for a class:

```
<?php

    class Vote
    {
        private $connect;

        public $topics = array();

        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->connect = new mysqli( '127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'Data' );

            if( $this->connect->connect_errno )
            {
                echo "Error:(" . $this->connect->connect_errno . "): " . $this->connect->connect_error . ".";
            }
        }

        public function GetTopics()
        {
            $Query = 'SELECT * FROM Topics';

            if( $Gather = $this->connect->query( $Query ) )
            {
                while( $Row = $Gather->fetch_assoc() )
                {
                    $this->topics[] = $Row['Topic'];
                }
                $Gather->free();
            }
            else
            {
                echo 'Error';
            }
        }

        public function LoadTopics()
        {
            if( $max = count($this->topics) > 0 )
            {
                $html = "<select>\r\n";

                for( $i = 0; $i < $max; ++$i )
                {
                    $html .= "<option value=" . $i . ">" . $this->topics[$i] . "</option>";
                }
                $html .= "</select>\r\n";

                return $html;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public function __destruct()
        {
            $this->connect->close();
        }
    }
?>
```

The __construct() / __destruct() methods are practically made to put your connection in. You could have also combined both functions and just have the `GetTopics()` method (I compulsively changed some method and property names) run the query, format the results and return the `$html`.

Also, I upgraded your `for` function, in case you decide to add another entry later to your topics, it will expand with it instead of it counting through 15 static rows.

You can call it with:

```
<?php

    $vote = new Vote();

    echo $vote->GetTopics()->LoadTopics();
?>
```

I saw the answer was already selected, didn't want my work to go to waste though ;D

Alternate `GetTopics()` function, all rolled into one.

```
        public function GetTopics()
        {
            $Query = 'SELECT * FROM Topics';

            if( $Gather = $this->connect->query( $Query ) )
            {
                $html = "<select>\r\n";
                $i = 0;

                while( $Row = $Gather->fetch_assoc() )
                {
                    $html .= "<option value=" . $i . ">" . $Row['Topic'] . "</option>";
                    ++i;
                }
                $html .= "</select>\r\n";

                $Gather->free();

                return $html;
            }
            else
            {
                return "Error: No Results Returned";
            }
        }
```

And now it's just called by:

```
<?php echo $vote->GetTopics(); ?>
```